# Fetching the particular post having post type page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm facing some problem when I fetch page content of particular Id. I'm using the code given below.

There is many pages in my database, I just want to show the page having `id =30` and `post_type=page`. When I'm using the code given below it show all page content having `post_type=page`. But I just only the one. I think there is some syntax problem in my code.

```
<?php  
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'page','ID'=> 30) );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
  the_content();
endwhile;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
global $wpdb;
$details = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE ID=30 and post_type='page'");
return $details;
```

or

```
<?php
  $args=array(
 'post_type'=>'page',
 'post__in' => array('595', '33', 44)
 );
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
?>
```

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for reply ,Is it not possible by using my code through little bit correction ? .

Answer (score 0):

Errm, what happened to good old `get_post(30)`?